# R: Count how many rows between two times

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to figure out how many people are in an office at a given time (between arrival and checkout times). I have a data frame with no NA values. I want to calculate volume per 5 minutes.

```
  library(timeDate)
    #change from factor to datetime
data$ArrivalDtm<- timeDate(data$ArrivalDtm)
data$CheckoutDtm<- timeDate(data$CheckoutDtm)
```

Then I created 5 minute blocks:

```
    #make a df of 5 minute intervals
blocks <- as.data.frame(seq(from= timeDate("2015-12-31 23:00:00"), to=timeDate("2017-06-13 23:00:00"), by='5 mins'))
```

Then I tried to iterate through the DF of visits to count how many people have checked in but have not check out at the block time.

```
for (i in blocks) {
  for (visit in 1:nrow(data)){
      waitingroom <- sum(data$ArrivalDtm[visit] > i & i < data$CheckoutDtm[visit])
  }
}
```

When i run the loop I get this error:

> Error in sum(data$ArrivalDtm[visit]) :    invalid 'type' (S4) of argument

Data

```
ArrivalDtm<- c("2016-05-10 20:34:00", "2016-04-13 22:46:00", "2016-12-15 13:18:00", "2016-02-26 18:32:00", "2016-04-25 13:55:00") 
CheckoutDtm <- c("2016-05-10 20:37:00", "2016-04-14 00:23:00", "2016-12-15 13:27:00", "2016-02-26 18:53:00", "2016-04-25 14:33:00")
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data to help those who may try to answer?

Comment: You have a right, not the best, approach but need to see some sample data to debug the error.

Comment: Here is some sample data. ArrivalDtm<- c("2016-05-10 20:34:00", "2016-04-13 22:46:00", "2016-12-15 13:18:00",  "2016-02-26 18:32:00",  "2016-04-25 13:55:00")

CheckoutDtm <- c("2016-05-10 20:37:00", "2016-04-14 00:23:00", "2016-12-15 13:27:00", "2016-02-26 18:53:00", "2016-04-25 14:33:00")

Comment: I am not married to this approach. In fact, I would love to learn a more elegant approach if you have suggestions.

Comment: Use `dput(data)` as your problem is caused by your data type. You can sample on data and just present part of it but still we need to know the type and the class i we want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a more elegant (and valid) way to do this:
I created 10 minute bins and the used lubridate to test if the span of visit overlapped with the bin and counted how many TRUE values there were for each bin. It takes a very long time to run--could be optimized. But it's a start.

```
diff <- make_difftime(minutes=10)
as.interval(diff, ymd_hms("2017-01-01 00:00:00"))
intervals <- as.interval(diff, seq(from= ymd_hms("2017-01-01 00:00:00"), to=ymd_hms("2017-06-13 23:00:00"), by='10 mins'))

span <- interval(recentdata$ArrivalDtm, recentdata$CheckoutDtm)


#int_overlaps(intervals,span)


waitingroom <- intervals
waitingroom <- as.data.frame(waitingroom)
waitingroom$count <- 0

for (interval in 1:length(intervals)){
  (waitingroom$count[interval] <- sum(int_overlaps(intervals[interval], span)==TRUE))
}
```